# posix_kill not working when run from browser

Tags: php, apache, process, kill-process, sigkill

I have a simple script, which tries to kill an already running process. I am using posix_kill for the same. The script runs fine, if I run it from command shell, but doesn't work when I run it from the browser.

```
<?php

    $taskid  = 33;
    killProcess($taskid);

    function killProcess($taskid) {
    $ppid = getPID($taskid);
    echo "process id -- $ppid\n";
    $pids = preg_split('/\s+/', `ps -o pid --no-heading --ppid $ppid`);
    var_dump($pids);
    foreach($pids as $pid) {
            if(is_numeric($pid)) {
            echo "Killing $pid\n";
                posix_kill($pid, 15);
            }
    }

    }
?>
```

I always get the following output, which means that the script is executing fine, but the process does not get killed:
        process id -- 4632
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
          1 => string '4633' (length=4)
          2 => string '' (length=0)
        Killing 4633

I checked out the apache "error.log" file, and found that for each run that I do from browser, and additional entry gets added as follows:
[Sat Jun 23 12:24:55 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

Unfortunately this error does not give me much information about what's going wrong. I checked out the php.ini settings, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong (as per whatever limited understanding I have). I do not see posix_kill in the "disabled_functions" list etc or any other setting that should prevent me from executing process.

Would sincerely appreciate some help !!

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message has nothing to do with your problem. It's just the browser asking for your site's icon, which you haven't configured.

Now, about the actual issue: the apache user likely doesn't have permissions to kill your process. If the process was started under a different user account, you can't kill it from within the web server. Imagine a multiuser system where any local user could log in and kill everyone else's processes - that isn't the Unix permissions model...

You might want to use a limited `sudo` with `exec`, or otherwise assume permissions before sending the signal. Or you could have the process listen for the web server to do something, and then kill *itself*. Or, better yet, don't use a web-serving language like PHP for systems-administration type tasks: use `cron` or a more appropriate tool.

Comment: Yes....that is precisely the reason.......I had fired the process from php daemon and was trying to kill it from browser...ofcourse it will not have the permissions to kill...thanks a lot Borealid !!